# Seeking to find a children's scifi series from mid-1980s

Tags: robots, space, story-identification

The first sci-fi I ever read was in the middle school library (appr 1988), and to be honest I was amazed it was even there, given the size of the library.  It could have fit into a McDonald's playland...

The book(s) was space travel and involved children as the main characters and at least one AI type robot.  I could have sworn Asimov wrote it, but I have tried to find any book that would be written by him and in a middle school's library. I also swear at least one of the books, if not all, have the word Robot in them.  I want to say there were three books, but this was so long ago, and my memory so fuzzy.  If anyone can think of possible candidates for this I would be most appreciative.  I would love to find these books again, somehow, and add them to my library.

I know the description is vague.  I apologise for this ahead of time.

Comment: Do you have anything else you remember?  The cover art?  Any character names?  Plot points?  Anything you can provide may help...

Answer (score 7):

Could possibly be the Norby series.

1. Written by Janet Asimov
2. Norby is an intelligent robot
3. Owner/partner is a child, Jefferson "Jeff" Wells.
4. First title is "Norby the mixed up robot"
5. There was a collection made where the second title had books #3 and 4 in the series, titled "Norby: Robot for hire" (Collection had 3 books, each one contained two stories)
6. Published dates run from 1983 - 1997 (First 6 books from 1983 - 1987)

That's about the closest I can find.

Note: [Wiki entry for Norby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norby)